# Multiple conditions then create a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF

```
Name  domain   av_rate   domain_rate

ABC    cat       55       22

DEF    dog       24       32

XYZ    cat       33       22

stu    dog       22       32
```

Desired O/P: Winner is the Name whose `av_rate>= domain_rate`

```
Name  domain   av_rate   domain_rate   Winner

ABC    cat       55       22             Yes

DEF    dog       24       32              No

XYZ    cat       33       22              Yes

stu    dog       22       32               No
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: `df['Winner']= np.where(df['av_rate'].ge(df['domain_rate']),"Yes","No")`

Comment: How can i add multiple conditions?

Comment: `np.select` check the link I added as dupe., your example has just one, if you can figure `np.select` let me know and I will help you